# Unable to create a webshot in R [TypeError: undefined is not an object]

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I would like to create a webshot of a flexdashboard html file. I managed to create the dashboard and generate its html file. However, I am not able to create a png webshot, as it returns an error.

This is the code I am using:

```
 rmarkdown::render(paste0(script.basedir, "dashboard.RMD"),
                    output_file = name_html,
                    output_dir = '.'
)

 webshot(name_html,
          file = name_png,
          delay = 15,
          vwidth = 1920,
          vheight = 1080)
```

This is the error I get:

```
PHANTOM ERROR: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'url.toLowerCase')
TRACE:
 -> phantomjs://platform/utils.js: 112 (in function cleanUrl)
 -> phantomjs://platform/casper.js: 1460 (in function open)
 -> phantomjs://platform/casper.js: 1949 (in function _step)
 -> phantomjs://platform/casper.js: 1615 (in function runStep)
 -> phantomjs://platform/casper.js: 406 (in function checkStep)
Error in webshot(name_html, file = name_png, delay = 15, vwidth = 1920,  : 
  webshot.js returned failure value: 1
```

Could anybody help me with this error, please?
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: There is a `)` missing in your code. Also: on what system are you on. Might be relevant for the question.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to copy that ')'. I added it to the question.

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Not really. I stopped using this.